# How can I handle the back button in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to handle the back button in my React Native application. I know that can use addEventListener in componentdidmount and componentWillUnmount to handle the back button.

My problem is, the page still exists in stack navigation, so on the other page I have the EventListener, but I want the EventListener on only one page.

The following example code from *[How to exit React Native app on back button pressed](https://inducesmile.com/react-native-source-code/how-to-exit-react-native-app-on-back-button-pressed/)* does not solve the problem.

Comment: Please show an example of the problematic code

Comment: Formatted text and syntax.

Comment: why edit and revive when this question is from 1 year ago and likely abandoned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `react-navigation`'s `withNavigationFocus` HOC.

Using it you know inside your screen if it's the focussed one or not. An example of an implementation would be:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress)
}

componentDidUpdate = (prevProps) => {
    if (prevProps.isFocused !== this.props.isFocused) {
        this.props.isFocused ?
        this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress):
        this.backHandler.remove()
    }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.backHandler.remove()
}
```

Don't forget to import withNavigationFocus and BackHandler:

```
import { withNavigationFocus } from "react-navigation";
import { BackHandler } from "react-native";
```

The in your export you have to do:

```
export default withNavigationFocus(*componentName*)
```

Comment: A word seems to be missing in *"The in your export"*.

Comment: What is the code near `this.props.isFocused ?` supposed to do? For instance, the syntax highlighter does not like it one bit.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [this solution](https://github.com/vonovak/react-navigation-backhandler).

It's easy as to wrap your component that is on the screen now with:

```
import { AndroidBackHandler } from 'react-navigation-backhandler';
<AndroidBackHandler onBackPress={this.onBackButtonPressAndroid}>
    <SomeComponent />
</AndroidBackHandler>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app navigator

```
function onBackPress() {
  if (Actions.state.index === 0) {
    return false;
  }
  Actions.pop();
  return true;
}



const AppNavigator = conn()(Router);

  return (
    <AppNavigator navigator={navigator} backAndroidHandler={onBackPress} />
  );
```

Comment: What does the last `return` do?